# Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey and Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError

Tags: node.js, docker, api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy an open source project (https://github.com/LiteFarmOrg/LiteFarm) on local host through docker composer and i have followed the instructions provided in the link, the app is a node.js app with frontend in react.js i have provided the (google_api_key) for the map to work in the application in the ".env" file but i am getting the error of "invalidkey" yet i tried to provide another newly generated key same error i faced. the screenshot is as

[invalid key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVANg.png)

also in the location text field the "icon of something went wrong is coming".

Comment: This is an error with Google Maps APIs. It seems that your API key is not being parsed correctly. I suggest that you file a [support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case) to Google Maps Platform technical support as they can further check the error.